# How can you explain Matthew 24:36?

Tags: catholicism, trinity, persons-of-the-trinity

Matthew 24:36 (NIV)

> But about that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in
> heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father.

I am aware that Jesus does not know the time of the final judgement in his human nature, but does in his divine nature.

The problem is, Jesus specifies "..but ***only*** the Father". This totally excludes the Holy Spirit. Why doesn't the Holy Spirit know of it despite being fully God?

I've searched for an answer for long and haven't yet got a logically satisfying explanation.

Comment: This is an astute and subtle question +1

Comment: I doubt you can prove from scripture that "_Jesus does not know the time of the final judgement in his human nature, but does in his divine nature._".

Comment: Jesus' point in this passage was to exhort the disciples to live in a state of readiness rather than teach on the Trinity. This verse does not exclude the Holy Spirit - it simply does not mention the Holy Spirit. The Lord's prayer does not mention the Holy Spirit either.

Answer (score 1):

The Trinity, simply because it gets at the very heart of God's being, is essentially outside the grasp of human explanation:  Theology, philosophy, metaphysical exploration all fall short.  And yet we must try.

> It is the glory of God to conceal a thing: but the honour of kings is to search out a matter. - Proverbs 25:2

One way to think about the Trinity is to start with God as having infinite, eternal, perfect integrity.  Because His integrity is perfect, there is no ontological difference between who He is, what He says, and what He does.  Because He is infinite, each of the three are fully God.  Because He is eternal, each of the three have always been.

The Father is who He is;
The Son (Logos) is what He says;
The Spirit is what He does (or how He does it)

This conception also allows for the theological ideas of the [procession](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/processions-trinitarian) of the Son and the [spiration](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/spiration) (or second generation) of the Spirit as exemplified in Jesus' statement (there are many such statements):

> But the Comforter, which is **the Holy Ghost, whom the Father will send in my name**, he shall teach you all things, and bring all things to your remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you. Peace I leave with you, my peace I give unto you: not as the world giveth, give I unto you. Let not your heart be troubled, neither let it be afraid. If ye loved me, ye would rejoice, because I said, I go unto the
> Father: for **my Father is greater than I**. - John 14:26-28

The Father is not more God than the Son or the Spirit but has primacy in the order of eternal procession. In this way, though the Spirit searches all things, even the deep things of God ([1 Cor. 2:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%202%3A10-16&version=KJV)) there is no requirement for the Spirit to [a-priori](https://www.britannica.com/topic/a-priori-knowledge) **know** all things.

It is quite all right for the Father to know something that the Spirit does not.

Comment: I am still unable to wrap my head around it since Holy Spirit **is** God. The Father communicates the divine nature to the Son. The Holy Spirit also has this indivisible divine nature. Shouldn't having this divine nature necessitate the possession of the knowledge of everything?

Comment: @Rich_Dragonfruit_789, the Church defines Trinity as a "Mystery".  e.g. [The Mystery of the Holy Trinity — Catholic Current](https://catholiccurrent.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/TWIM-4-26-Catechetical-Corner-English.pdf). According to the [Catholic Encyclopedia: Mystery](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/10662a.htm) "*signifies in general that which is unknowable, or valuable knowledge that is kept secret … a supernatural truth, one that of its very nature lies above the finite intelligence.*". The fact that you are "unable to wrap my head around it" indicates that you get it.